# Node q promise handler not called with an already defined function

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I might be missing something at some point, but I don't quite get why this is working:

```
  app.post('/check-setup-auth', function(req, res) {
    db.isAuthorizedToInstall()
    .then(function(data) {
      res.status(200).json(data);
    });
  });
```

Whereas this, doesn't

```
  app.post('/check-setup-auth', function(req, res) {
    db.isAuthorizedToInstall()
    .then(res.status(200).json);
  });
```

I was expecting that to result in the exact same thing, but somehow the resolve data from the promise is not passed to the res.json function; or the function is not getting called.

I'm using:

- Linux 3.19.0-31-generic #36-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- nodejs v4.1.1
- express 2.14.4

Comment: Yes, looks like it's a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is a big difference between the 2 codes.

In the first code, `res.status(200)` is executed after the `db.isAuthorizedToInstall()` end.

In the second code, `res.status(200)` is executed before the `db.isAuthorizedToInstall()` end.

`res.status(200)` begin the write of the headers of the response. So it can prevent some other codes to write in the response.

I think the function is called in the second code, but the behavior of the response is not the same. So you may have some other code breaking this.